# docker container run gradle test: how to avoid dependencies download everytime?

Tags: docker, gradle, caching, docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  
  test:
    image: image_based_on_gradle
    command: ["gradle", "test"]
```

Every time the container starts, "gradle test" will download all dependencies, not cached.

```
 > docker-compose run test
 ...
 Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.pom to /home/gradle/.gradle/.tmp/gradle_download8543351628532152618bin

 ... (long list of Downloads)
```

The gradle image defines the following volume:

```
 VOLUME /home/gradle/.gradle
```

Is it for caching? but downloaded artifacts are not cached in the volume.

Inside dockerfile, the following option works:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/gradle/.gradle gradle build
```

How to add this in the service command?

```
command: ["gradle", "test"]
```